# Add array line by line to csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am using `PHP 7.1.33` and I want to add an array line by line to a file.

I tried the following:

```
<?php

$posts = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

function array2csv($data, $delimiter = ';', $enclosure = '"', $escape_char = "\\")
{
    $f = fopen('data/array2file.csv', 'r+');
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        fputcsv($f, $item, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escape_char);
    }
    rewind($f);
    return stream_get_contents($f);
}

array2csv($posts);
```

However, I get the following error:

> fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

I just want to have a csv file that looks like the following:

```
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
```

So for each line the output of the array.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: So it looks like the file was not opened. When `fopen()` fails it returns a boolean `false`

Comment: Does `'data/array2file.csv'` already exist?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No the file does not exist. Any suggestions how to create the file if it does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$posts = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

function array2csv($data, $delimiter = ';', $enclosure = '"', $escape_char = "\\")
{
    $f = fopen('data/array2file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        fputcsv($f, [$item], $delimiter, $enclosure, $escape_char);
    }
    fclose($f);
}

array2csv($posts);
```

Comment: **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.